# Python pandas header specification vs date formatting

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder why the datetime format depends on whether the header parameter in read_excel is None or not.

I try to convert excel file to CSV format without any data manipulation, processing, conversions etc. Plain change of format.

The excel file (single column formatted as date):

```
Date1
07.01.2019
```

```py
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, ignore_index=True, dtype=object)
print(df)
```

gives:

```
       Date1
0 2019-01-07
```

On the other hand, setting header to None gives different output:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, ignore_index=True, dtype=object, header=None)
print(df)
```

gives:

```
                     0
0                Date1
1  2019-01-07 00:00:00
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Setting header to 'None' tells pandas that there are no headers in the .xlsx and the first row of the .xlsx is data. Therefore the first row of the dataframe is 'Date1', with a column name of 0, since you didn't specify any header names. The docs should point you in the right direction: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Thank you. May be I was not clear, but the point is: when called without header parameter I have: "2019-01-07" and with header=None I have: "2019-01-07 00:00:00" as date value.

Comment: That is because with header = None the dtype is an Object, and with a header it is a date. I think your question is more to do with date formatting than the inclusion of headers. The read_excel has several built in functions to deal with dates.

Comment: Thank you. Hmm, well dtype is set to object in both cases. From manual "Use object to preserve data as stored in Excel and not interpret dtype". So I would expect same output independently if header is set or not set to None.